# How to convert instance of any type to string?

Tags: javascript

I'm implementing a function that receives an argument which it needs to convert to its string representation.

If a given object implements a `toString()` method, then the function should use it.  Otherwise, the function can rely on what the JavaScript implementation offers.

What I come up with is like this:

```
var convert = function (arg) {
  return (new String(arg)).valueOf();
}
```

Comment: Could you mark as the proper answer this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61216101/3345644), since it's the recommended way to do the job in modern JS engines?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I'm not sure you even need a function, but this would be the shortest way:

```
function( arg ) {
    return arg + '';
}
```

Otherwise this is the shortest way:

```
arg += '';
```

Comment: This is not the shirtest way anymore. For modern JS engines, see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61216101/3345644) below.

Answer (score 68):

`String(null)` returns - "null"

`String(undefined)` returns - "undefined"

`String(10)` returns - "10"

`String(1.3)` returns - "1.3"

`String(true)` returns - "true"

`String(new Error("foo"))` returns - "Error: foo"

I think this is a more elegant way.

Answer (score 23):

```
value = value+"";
```

Comment: isn't it same as value+="" from accepted answer

Answer (score 14):

If targeting ES6 or later, you could use a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals):

```
function (arg) {
    return `${arg}`;
}
```

Comment: @Namrata Sorry, your issue with eslint is irrelevant to the OP's Q. Your issue is not a JavaScript compiler error. So, my answer is completely fine. eslint is just a 3rd party code style inspector tool and is not related to the original Q `How to convert instance of any type to string in JavaScript?`.

Answer (score 6):

All data types in JavaScript inherit a **`toString`** method:

```
('hello').toString();   // "hello"
(123).toString();       // "123"
([1,2,3]).toString();   // "1,2,3"
({a:1,b:2}).toString(); // "[object Object]"
(true).toString();      // "true"
```

Comment: but this doesn't work with..

    (undefined).toString(); // error
    (null).toString(); // error

Answer (score 5):

These are all great answers, but here comes the ultimate solution that covers all the cases :)

```js
function stringify(value) {
  switch (typeof value) {
    case 'string': case 'object': return JSON.stringify(value);
    default: return String(value);
  }
};

for (const value of [
  null,
  undefined,
  12345,
  'abcdef',
  true,
  false,
  BigInt(9007199254740991),
  NaN,
  Symbol('sym'),
  [1, 2, 3],
  {aaa: 'AAA', bbb: 'BBB'},
  (a, b) => a + b,
  stringify,
]) {
  console.log(stringify(value));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`JSON.stringify(value)`

Works for null, undefined, primitives, arrays and objects — basically everything.

Comment: Note: `JSON.stringify(undefined)` will return `undefined` not `"undefined"`

Answer (score 1):

The other answers are incomplete when it comes to a JSON object passed. So I made this one and it works for all:

```html
var getString = (o) => {
    if (o !== null) {
        if (typeof o === 'string') {
            return o;
        } else {
            return JSON.stringify(o);
        }
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should also handle `false` and `0`. These two will return `null` with your snippet. Simply change `if (o)` to `if (o !== null)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
/* use back tic; same key as tilde(~) typically, and ${} */
const myString = `${value}`;
```

Short way to convert most types to String, but some types such as Objects will stringify their type [object Object]. For those

```
/**
 * @typedef {Object} replacerProps
 * @property {any} this - the replacer function.
 * @property {string} key - the key of the current node passed to the replacer.
 * @property {any} value - the data of the current node passed to the replacer.
 */
/**
 * @param {any} value - data to stringify.
 * @param {((replacerProps) => any)|undefined} [replacer=null] - A function 
 *  that alters the behavior of the stringification process, or an array
 *  of String and Number that serve as an allowlist for selecting/filtering
 *  the properties of the value object to be included in the JSON string. If 
 *  this value is null or not provided, all properties of the object are
 *  included in the resulting JSON string.
 * @param {string|number} [space=null] - insert whitespace for readability.
 *  If null, no whitespace is used.
 * @returns {string|undefined} a JSON string representing the given 
 *  value or undefined.
 */
JSON.stringify(value, null, 0);
```

JSON.stringify() is the best catch-all solution.